# Two independent monitors in Dual-Head? Problems

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, gnome3, calibration, xinerama

I want to move to Linux but I have a little problem I need to resolve.

I have a nvidia card with two monitors. The problem is that the secondary one is kinda crap and need a calibration to make it works good.

As far I know, with TwinView I can't calibrate my second monitor because TwinView treats my dualhead as a single big monitor.

So I heard about Xinerama. With Xinerama I can calibrate my monitors without any problem. So far so good.

The problem is that Xinerama doesn't support composite. So gnome will not work.

So, questions:

I read in internet something about nvidia doesnt make Xinerama + composite works. So, the Xinerama + composite is a generic problem or just of nvidia privative driver?

With nouveau, can I get Xinerama working?

I ask this because I'm on a Mint live (gnome fallback) and through gnome settings, I have two independent monitors working that can be calibrated.

Is this because nvidia propietary drivers are not working or is because is gnome fallback that doesn't have any composite?

Any ideas ? :)

Comment: What version of linux, nvidia drivers tried, etc?

Comment: Linux Mint, nvidia 280. Anyway is a problem on every linux, and nvidia privative drivers, that's why I ask for an alternative.

Comment: I've ran Ubuntu 11.04 with NVidia GTX560Ti graphics cards just fine. Both in single and multiple monitor configurations.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 11.04 with that same driver. I use the nvidia-settings panel instead of the default monitors panel that comes with Gnome. I use TwinView and am able to get both monitors working. With more detail in your question, you might have better luck if you flag it for a moderator to migrate to askubuntu. (Mint and Ubuntu are *very* similar.) By detail, I mean your xorg.conf, how you installed the driver, where you got it, etc, and also what settings you've set in the nvidia-settings panel.

Comment: My problem is about having two independent monitors so I can calibrate them, obviously twinview works for seeing the desktop, but I can't calibrate them because twinview is just like one big monitor instead of two.